# MySQL Cursor silently removing trailing space

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursors

I am writing a stored procedure that fetches some data from a given column and does work on them, the problem is some of that data contains trailing spaces and when the data is read into a temporary table in the stored procedure for some reason those trailing spaces are removed (I need them kept).

I have narrowed down the culprit to the declaration of the cursor..

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT element, LENGTH(element) FROM tmpTable;

If I print out what the cursor contains in each loop the element is something like '1234' but the length is 8.. which is what i want since the original data was '1234    '.

Any ideas on how to make the cursor read everything and not silently trim the trailing spaces?

Comment: Did you get your question answered below by me. Please comment, upvote, downvote, accept answer, or something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem.

Note the difference between [LENGTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_length) and [CHAR_LENGTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length).

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.13    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tmpTable`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `demo_sp`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmpTable` (
    ->   `element_utf8` VARCHAR(50),
    ->   `element_latin1` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci
    -> ) CHARACTER SET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `tmpTable`
    ->   (`element_utf8`, `element_latin1`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   (CONCAT('1234', SPACE(5)), CONCAT('1234', SPACE(5))),
    ->   ('áéíóú', 'áéíóú');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `element_utf8`,
    ->   `element_latin1`,
    ->   LENGTH(`element_utf8`),
    ->   CHAR_LENGTH(`element_utf8`),
    ->   LENGTH(`element_latin1`),
    ->   CHAR_LENGTH(`element_latin1`)
    -> FROM
    ->   `tmpTable`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                 element_utf8: 1234     
               element_latin1: 1234     
       LENGTH(`element_utf8`): 9
  CHAR_LENGTH(`element_utf8`): 9
     LENGTH(`element_latin1`): 9
CHAR_LENGTH(`element_latin1`): 9
*************************** 2. row ***************************
                 element_utf8: áéíóú
               element_latin1: áéíóú
       LENGTH(`element_utf8`): 10
  CHAR_LENGTH(`element_utf8`): 5
     LENGTH(`element_latin1`): 5
CHAR_LENGTH(`element_latin1`): 5
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `demo_sp`()
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `_not_found` BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
    ->   DECLARE `_length_utf8`,
    ->           `_char_length_utf8`,
    ->           `_length_latin1`,
    ->           `_char_length_latin1` INT UNSIGNED;
    -> 
    ->   DECLARE `demo_cursor` CURSOR FOR
    ->     SELECT
    ->       LENGTH(`element_utf8`),
    ->       CHAR_LENGTH(`element_utf8`),
    ->       LENGTH(`element_latin1`),
    ->       CHAR_LENGTH(`element_latin1`)
    ->     FROM
    ->       `tmpTable`;
    ->   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `_not_found` := TRUE;
    -> 
    ->   OPEN `demo_cursor`;
    -> 
    ->   `read_loop`: LOOP
    ->     FETCH `demo_cursor` INTO `_length_utf8`,
    ->                              `_char_length_utf8`,
    ->                              `_length_latin1`,
    ->                              `_char_length_latin1`;
    -> 
    ->     IF (`_not_found`) THEN
    ->       CLOSE `demo_cursor`;
    ->       LEAVE `read_loop`;
    ->     END IF;
    -> 
    ->     SELECT `_length_utf8`,
    ->            `_char_length_utf8`,
    ->            `_length_latin1`,
    ->            `_char_length_latin1`;
    ->   END LOOP;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `demo_sp`;
+----------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| `_length_utf8` | `_char_length_utf8` | `_length_latin1` | `_char_length_latin1` |
+----------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
|              9 |                   9 |                9 |                     9 |
+----------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+----------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| `_length_utf8` | `_char_length_utf8` | `_length_latin1` | `_char_length_latin1` |
+----------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
|             10 |                   5 |                5 |                     5 |
+----------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```